# Force tabs in the Dart Editor

Tags: dart

Any way to **force** the Dart Editor to use damn tabs instead of spaces?

I've tried for months to use the whole 2 space nonsense and it's honestly done nothing more then made it a hassle to navigate code at the line level as well as a pain in many other respects such as fixing / refactoring bits of code. Could care less for people who can't adjust their tab indentation from 8 to 4, I've honestly never encountered a system where I couldn't customize the editor to a reasonable tab width—and as far as I'm concerned that's the only reason to have spaces instead of tabs given by the dart team.